# Is it possible to replicate reverse DNS zones?

Tags: windows-server-2003

We migrated our DNS servers from Linux onto Windows 2003 AD-based. Is it possible to replicate the reverse zones? We have about 6 DNS servers and it would suck if I had to go into each server to add a PTR address. I've been adding new A records on a local DNS server and things have been working as expected. However, the reverse mapping doesn't propagate between DNS servers.

Comment: Figured it out ... someone had set a filter so I wasn't able to see the entries. However, that doesn't explain why i wasn't able to run a reverse lookup. THings are working fine now. No idea what was going on.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, You need to set the Reverse Lookup Zones to be Active Directory Integrated and choose a replication partition.

Comment: They're set to be "AD-Integrated"

Comment: They you need to troubleshoot your replication.  Are the other DNS servers in the same AD site/ subnet?  What is your replication partition set to?

Comment: Mind you I'm a linux guy and I haven't touched Windows in years. Yes to the DNS servers being in the same AD site but subnet wise they are not. We have servers in 3 different locations. Weird, i dont see anything in the logs and the standard records work perfectly.

Comment: Are all of your subnets added to your AD Site in the AD Sites & Subnets MMC?

Comment: Ok looks like it's working all of a sudden. See my edits.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible. In your DNS server, you have to go into the DNS management console and either *create* the "Reverse Lookup Zone(s)" you need or right-click on the properties for that zone. You can set the replication parameters there.

[image]

[image]